# What is the best way to move the content of an enumerable objects to an array of objects? See code below

Tags: c#

```
public object[] GetByteCodes(IEnumerable<byte> enumerableByteCodes)
{

     object[] objects = new object[enumerableByteCodes.Count()];

     //What the next step here?...

     return objects;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do those bytes in enumerableByteCodes represent objects? If not, why are you not returning a byte[]?

If you want to return a byteArray, you can just use the LINQ extension method on

`IEnumerable<t>.ToArray()`;

If you want to return it as an object you can use the Select LINQ extension to do that too.

`enumerableByteCodes.Select(t=> (object)t).ToArray();`

You could also use

`enumerableBytes.OfType<object>().ToArray();`

Answer (score 2):

```
byteCodes = enumerableByteCodes.ToArray();
```

I would simply make the function:

```
public byte[] GetByteCode(IEnumerable<byte> enumerableByteCodes)
{
    return enumerableByteCodes.ToArray();
}
```

Why are you using `object[]`, seeing as your generic type is a `byte`?

Update:

Since you must have an `object[]`, you need to cast each member:

```
public object[] GetByteCode(IEnumerable<byte> enumerableByteCodes)
{
    return enumerableByteCodes.Select(x => (object)x).ToArray();
}
```